# Not able to reproduce the statement that spectral power of natural images falls with frequency as 1/f**2

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, computer-vision, fft

As the title says, I am trying to reproduce the following statement from (1)

> Empirically, many authors have found that the spectral power of
>   natural images falls with frequency, f, according to a power law,
>   1/f**p, with estimated values for p typically near 2.

For this purpose, I used the code from (2) with some minor modifications

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import pylab as pl
from scipy.stats import linregress
from skimage import color

# Load image in greyscale
image = color.rgb2gray(mpimg.imread("clouds.png"))
image_X,image_Y = image.shape[0], image.shape[1]

# Do FFT
fourier_image = np.fft.fftn(image)
fourier_amplitudes = np.abs(fourier_image)**2

# Get wave vector
kfreq_X = np.fft.fftfreq(image_X) * image_X
kfreq_Y = np.fft.fftfreq(image_Y) * image_Y
kfreq2D = np.meshgrid(kfreq_X, kfreq_Y)
knrm = np.sqrt(kfreq2D[0]**2 + kfreq2D[1]**2)

knrm = knrm.flatten()
fourier_amplitudes = fourier_amplitudes.flatten()

kbins = np.arange(0.5, max(image_X, image_Y)/2 + 1., 1.)
kvals = 0.5 * (kbins[1:] + kbins[:-1])

Abins, _, _ = stats.binned_statistic(knrm, fourier_amplitudes,
                                     statistic = "mean",
                                     bins = kbins)
Abins *= 4. * np.pi / 3. * (kbins[1:]**3 - kbins[:-1]**3)

# print(linregress(np.log(kvals[20:-300]), np.log(Abins[20:-300])))

# pl.plot(kvals, Abins)
pl.loglog(kvals, Abins)
pl.xlabel("$k$")
pl.ylabel("$P(k)$")
pl.tight_layout()
pl.savefig("cloud_power_spectrum.png", dpi = 300, bbox_inches = "tight")
```

When I look at power spectrum of the image used in tutorial (2) my p estimate is around -1.3.
[image: clouds_power_spectrum]

When I tried with my own RGB image. I would not get nice power spectrum distribution as described and shown in (2). Instead, there are few peaks.
[image]
[image]

**Questions**
 1. Since I am not able to get even close to p~-2 for any of the images, I was wondering if my code is correct?
 2. If the code is okay, is there any other reason why I am not able to get p~-2?
 3. Are those peaks in RGB image some artefact of my conversion to grayscale maybe or this is expected behaviour?

(1) https://www.cns.nyu.edu/pub/eero/simoncelli01-reprint.pdf
(2) https://bertvandenbroucke.netlify.app/2019/05/24/computing-a-power-spectrum-in-python/

Comment: [The blog from which you adapted the code was corrected by the author on March 10, 2021.](https://bertvandenbroucke.netlify.app/2019/05/24/computing-a-power-spectrum-in-python/)

Comment: Nicolas, thank you very much both for the comment and the answer. I will try to read and go through this in the next week or two. Little bit short with the time at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Bert Vandenbroucke updated the [blog post from which OP obtained the code](https://bertvandenbroucke.netlify.app/2019/05/24/computing-a-power-spectrum-in-python/) on  March 10, 2021 to address a number of issues, among them:

Bin area formula `4. * np.pi / 3. * (kbins[1:]**3 - kbins[:-1]**3)` (3D spherical shell bin volume) was corrected to `np.pi * (kbins[1:]**2 - kbins[:-1]**2)` (2D ring bin area).

There is now a warning that frequencies above 1D Nyquist (0.5 cycle per pixel), that is, frequencies between 1D and 2D Nyquist (0.5*sqrt(2) cycle per pixel), are not correctly sampled. Original code completely broke down with a Nyquist checkerboard (alternating black and white pixels) with witdh=height=(power of 2).